# Export to CSV a list of addresses that fall within a shapefile?

Tags: shapefile, kml, merge, kmz, google-earth-pro

I currently have a shapefile (KML, but I also have it in other formats as well) that outlines neighborhoods within a city.  I also have a list of vacant property addresses in CSV.

I'm currently importing the addresses into Google Earth (GE) over the shapefile, but I don't think GE will do what I want.

I would like to be able to add data fields from the neighborhood shapefile such to the imported addresses and be able to export all the addresses to a CSV file and include the neighborhood shapefile data for the neighborhood they are in based on the shapefile.

Here is a screenshot of the neighborhood shapefile info:

[image: Example of shapefile info]

Here is a screenshot of the imported address info:

[image]

Comment: Can Google Earth perform a spatial join?  Do you have other GIS software available?

Comment: I've not seen an option for spatial join with GE but I was able to do it with ArcGIS trial account, however I don't want to pay $2,500 for just this.

Answer (score 1):

Google Earth cannot do spatial joins or perform other vector analysis functions, so it will not be able to do this for you.

I suggest you take a look at QGIS, the free and open-source GIS package which can absolutely do this. You'll be able to import your shapefile (Add Vector Layer) and address CSV (Add Delimited Text Layer), and use the vector analysis tools including Point in Polygon, Spatial Query, etc.

Here is a good tutorial that walks you though the details:
http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/points_in_polygon.html